# Record screen from memory of Linux

Tags: python, linux, screen, capture

**So , basically I want to design an app that record the screen not by capturing the screen as below**

```
import datetime

from PIL import ImageGrab
import numpy as np
import cv2

time_stamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S')
file_name = f'{time_stamp}.mp4'
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m', 'p', '4', 'v')
captured_video = cv2.VideoWriter(file_name, fourcc, 20.0, (630, 330))

while True:
    img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0, 0, 630, 330))
    img_np = np.array(img)
    img_final = cv2.cvtColor(img_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    cv2.imshow("Screen Recorder", img_final)
    captured_video.write(img_final)
    if cv2.waitKey(10) == ord('q'):
        break
```

It give the screen capturing but I need to record a specific process
Like

I want to record the screen output of

```
process 31328
```

Nothing else. Means while recording the screen the pop ups or any mini windows or any floating window opened during the recording would not capture in our screen recorder.

**I am thinking that the Linux will throw the output on screen like
We print ('hello'). We should grab that output before it reaches on screen and record it. Is it possible?**

Comment: Do you think of just text output, or also graphics output?

Comment: Everything which that process throw on screen include graphics and text like on GUI all things are displayed by coding and we can change them